# Only the User LED 2 gets solid on after reflashing my Beaglebone Black. I cant conect. Why?

Tags: embedded, debian, beagleboneblack, flash-memory

I've tryed several times to re-flash my Beaglebone Black with some images downloaded from the beagleboard website and elinux website, following these instructions to re-flash:

http://derekmolloy.ie/write-a-new-image-to-the-beaglebone-black/

And after the process is done (all user leds are solid off), i take off the micro sd and switch on the board and all user leds start to blink (not all together) and a few second later only the user led 2 keeps on (solid) and I cant acess it.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that for any reason reflashing hadnt completed. That's why the user led 2 was always solid on and all the other leds solid off.

After I insert the micro sd back I could access the board. To reflash I decided to setup the standalone microSD image to automatically flash the eMMC on powerup by editing /boot/uEnv.txt:

```
##enable BBB: eMMC Flasher:
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

Changing to:

```
##enable BBB: eMMC Flasher:
cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

and rebooting the system. It flashes the eMMC on the next bootup. (make sure to remove the microSD after flashing is complete)